# Rails 4 - How to mock the exception with custom response using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rspec, rest-client

In rails 4, I am using rspec for writing a test cases. Currently I want to mock one service call which raises Exception and returns required(custom) output.

Eg:

```
allow(RestClient).to receive(:post).and_raise(User::APIError)
```

and its response should be like `.and_return(error_response)`

`error_response` is equal to an object which can be anything.

Please help me to write a spec for this condition.

Comment: What do you mean by _"and returns custom output"_? Do you mean the raised exception has a message assigned and you want to test that the message is correct? Or does it output an error message to a log file?

Comment: Yes, raised exception should return a message which I want to pass separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would mock it like this:

```
allow(RestClient).to receive(:post).and_raise(User::APIError, 'custom error message')
```

See docs about [mocking errors](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error)

You can then test that the exception is raised with a specific message like this.

```
expect { method_calling_the_API }
  .to raise_error(an_instance_of(User::APIError)
  .and having_attributes(message: 'custom error message'))
```

See [RSpec docs for error matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an instance double which responds to a particular method. Example:

```rb
api_error = instance_double(User::APIError, method_name: error_response)
allow(RestClient).to receive(:post).and_raise(api_error)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Getting an error like `User::APIError class does not implement the instance method: method_name`

Comment: It's because `User::APIError` doesn't implement the `method_name` method. You'll have to change `method_name` to whatever method you're trying to call on the `User::API` instance.